# Https proxy server(secure proxy server) in Nodejs with http-proxy is not working

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I have a requirement to set up an https proxy server(Secure Web Proxy-http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy) to test one of my application with the proxy environment.

**Steps followed**: 
1.Created an https proxy server with the help of http-proxy. code,

```
    var https = require('https'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util'),
    fs   = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    colors = require('colors'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
   // fixturesDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test', 'fixtures'),   
    httpsOpts = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt', 'utf8')
    };

//
// Create the target HTTPS server
//
https.createServer(httpsOpts, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('hello https\n');
  res.end();
}).listen(9010);

//
// Create the proxy server listening on port 8010
//
httpProxy.createServer({
  ssl: httpsOpts,
  target: 'https://localhost:9010',
  secure: false
}).listen(8010);

console.log('https proxy server'.blue + ' started '.green.bold + 'on port '.blue + '8010'.yellow);
console.log('https server '.blue + 'started '.green.bold + 'on port '.blue + '9010 '.yellow);
```

2. Created a PAC file with https proxy server details

> ```
> function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {    
>   return "HTTPS 127.0.0.1:8010";
> }
> ```

3. And point the pac file in my application to test application with proxy environment, sample code pasted here.

> ```
> var url = require('url');
> var https = require('https');
> var PacProxyAgent = require('pac-proxy-agent');
>
> // URI to a PAC proxy file to use (the "pac+" prefix is stripped)
> var proxy = 'pac+http://localhost:123/hosted/pac.pac';
> //console.log('using PAC proxy proxy file at %j', proxy);
>
> // HTTP endpoint for the proxy to connect to
> var endpoint = 'https://nodejs.org/api/';
> //console.log('attempting to GET %j', endpoint);
> var opts = url.parse(endpoint);
>
> // create an instance of the `PacProxyAgent` class with the PAC file location
> var agent = new PacProxyAgent(proxy,opts);
> opts.agent = agent;
>
> https.get(opts, function (res) {
>   console.log('"response" event!', res.headers);
>   res.pipe(process.stdout);
> });
> ```

But it's not working, it throws the error

[image]

Chrome behavior:

I configured the PAC file in windows proxy settings 
[image]

After that I am not getting any response from any sites 
ex: when I enter https://gmail.com/ it ends up with

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure this out using a PAC file for Windows Proxy?